# Docker selenium firefox image creation issue

Tags: docker, selenium-docker

I'm trying to create a selenium firefox node image. I've added the "**COPY generate_config /opt/bin/generate_config**" command to copy the generate_config file from local. Then when I run the command "**RUN /opt/bin/generate_config > /opt/selenium/config.json**" , I get error -
**# #10 0.320 /bin/sh: 1: /opt/bin/generate_config: not found

## ------**

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/bin/generate_config > /opt/selenium/config.json]: exit code: 127

Can anyone please help me with solution

I tried adding sudo, changing the cat command. nothing worked.

Comment: Is it executable?  What kind of file is it?  If it's a script, does it have a "shebang" line, does the named interpreter exist, and does the file have Unix and not DOS line endings?

Comment: yes the generate_config file has shebang  lines